# DPDocker and Joomla

Tags: development, extensions, docker

I'm new to Docker. I tested https://github.com/Digital-Peak/DPDocker. I was able to implement things quickly with the component https://github.com/Digital-Peak/DPAttachments.

Now I'm in the process of converting one of my components.

I am currently creating symlinks with https://robo.li/. I wanted to keep it that way.
I use this component for the first tests: https://github.com/astridx/boilerplate

After symlinking via

```
astrid@ubuntu:~/git/DPDocker/boilerplate$ vendor/bin/robo map ~/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4/
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/language/de-DE/pkg_foos.ini","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//language/de-DE/pkg_foos.ini"]
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/language/de-DE/pkg_foos.sys.ini","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//language/de-DE/pkg_foos.sys.ini"]
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/language/en-GB/pkg_foos.ini","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//language/en-GB/pkg_foos.ini"]
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/language/en-GB/pkg_foos.sys.ini","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//language/en-GB/pkg_foos.sys.ini"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//api/components/com_foos...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/api/components/com_foos","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//api/components/com_foos"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//components/com_foos...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/components/com_foos","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//components/com_foos"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//plugins/webservices/foos...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/plugins/webservices/foos","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//plugins/webservices/foos"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//templates/facile...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/templates/facile","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//templates/facile"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//administrator/components/com_foos...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/administrator/components/com_foos","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//administrator/components/com_foos"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//media/com_foos...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/media/com_foos","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//media/com_foos"]
 [Filesystem\DeleteDir] Deleted /home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//modules/mod_foo...
 [Filesystem\FilesystemStack] symlink ["/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/boilerplate/src/modules/mod_foo","/home/astrid/git/DPDocker/DPDocker/webserver/www/j4//modules/mod_foo"]
astrid@ubuntu:~/git/DPDocker/boilerplate$
```

I see the attached and the extension is not found in Joomla. What is my mistake?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
I need to set the symlinks in the container. I posted it here in more detail: https://github.com/Digital-Peak/DPDocker/pull/10

Comment: We are going to need you to post the crux of the resolution here in your answer.  Stack Exchange (the entire network) has a hard rule about not wanting link-only answers.  Dead/Moved links are vulnerable to breakage -- these breakages render an entire page as a useless deadend for researchers.  Please explain exactly what you did.